# bidirectional onetomany on spring boot and hibernate, best way to save

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, one-to-many, many-to-one

I have 2 entities:

```
@Data
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@Table(name = "source_company")
public class SourceCompany {
    @Id
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private UUID id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany( mappedBy = "company")
    private final Set<SourceUser> users = new HashSet<>();

    @Column(name = "version")
    @Version
    private Long version;
}

@Data
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@Table(name = "source_user")
public class SourceUser {
    @Id
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private UUID id;

    private String name;

    @Column(name = "version")
    @Version
    private Long version;

    //ref
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_source_company")
    private SourceCompany company;
}
```

Is it correct to save in this way (only 2 save)?

```
        @Test
    public void testSourceUserSave() {
        SourceCompany sourceCompany= new SourceCompany();
        sourceCompany.setName("xxx");
        sourceCompany.setId(UUID.fromString("2bf05cbc-d530-11eb-b8bc-0242ac130003"));

        SourceUser sourceUser= new SourceUser();
        sourceUser.setName("dev-team");
        sourceUser.setId(UUID.fromString("4bede7a0-d530-11eb-b8bc-0242ac130003"));

        sourceUser.setCompany(sourceCompany);
        sourceCompany.getUsers().add(sourceUser);

        sourceCompanyRepository.save(sourceCompany);
        sourceUserRepository.save(sourceUser);

        assertNotNull(sourceUser);
        assertEquals(sourceUser.getCompany().getId(), sourceCompany.getId());
        assertEquals(sourceCompany.getUsers().stream().findFirst().get().getId(), sourceUser.getId());

    }
```

or I need to save the user (without company) and the company (without user) and after that to update the user with a save and the company (without save because is not the owner) like this (3 save):

```
        @Test
    public void testSourceUserSave() {
        SourceCompany sourceCompany= new SourceCompany();
        sourceCompany.setName("xxx");
        sourceCompany.setId(UUID.fromString("2bf05cbc-d530-11eb-b8bc-0242ac130003"));

        SourceUser sourceUser= new SourceUser();
        sourceUser.setName("dev-team");
        sourceUser.setId(UUID.fromString("4bede7a0-d530-11eb-b8bc-0242ac130003"));

        sourceUserRepository.save(sourceUser);
        sourceCompanyRepository.save(sourceCompany);

        sourceUser.setCompany(sourceCompany);
        sourceCompany.getUsers().add(sourceUser);

        sourceUserRepository.save(sourceUser);

        assertNotNull(sourceUser);
        assertEquals(sourceUser.getCompany().getId(), sourceCompany.getId());
        assertEquals(sourceCompany.getUsers().stream().findFirst().get().getId(), sourceUser.getId());

    }
```

It seems, looking in the db, that the first way works, so in future can I update only the owner side (I mean update and save) and so can I update the not-owner side only in the object without save it again?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You usually tend to save only one of the objects. This can be done adding the

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
```

to the mapping annotation. This makes sure that the nested entities get persisted too
You would need to do just:

```
SourceCompany sourceCompany= new SourceCompany();
sourceCompany.setName("xxx");
sourceCompany.setId(UUID.fromString("2bf05cbc-d530-11eb-b8bc-0242ac130003"));

SourceUser sourceUser= new SourceUser();
sourceUser.setName("dev-team");
sourceUser.setId(UUID.fromString("4bede7a0-d530-11eb-b8bc-0242ac130003"));

sourceUser.setCompany(sourceCompany);

sourceUserRepository.save(sourceUser);
```

One more thing to note is that the .save method actually returns an entity itself. That entity is the persisted entity just created. Basically if you manage everything within a single transactional method any modification to the persisted entity within that method (transaction) will be applied without calling any save, merge or update method
I suggest reading about the @Transactional annotation

Comment: Thank you. In any case my first example with 2 save and without cascade is correct? Can you explain to me why the cascade is on the many-to-one side (I see a lot of example with the cascade on the one-to-many side)? The last one of this for example: https://medium.com/@rajibrath20/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate-dbbf6dba00d3

Comment: It really depends on what you plan on your use case to be. You'll always have a main 'character' here. If you tend to save new employees with a pre-existing company one at a time you can put the persist cascade only on the employee side, and vice-versa if you're trying to save multiple employees at once.
You're example may not work because you're calling save on the user twice. You should add @Transactional to the method as I did and modified the user returned by the .save()

Comment: Sorry again, but my first example seems to work without cascade, because I save the company (the user is in the set but in db there isn't a reference! it is on user table side with the company column beacause is the owner), so I think that I saved a company with users (in the object) and without users in the db, after that I save the user with the reference to the company.

Comment: Sorry I misread. I thought you saved the user twice. Yes so in that case it's going to work. However it's not a best practice